# v-for loop select mutiple items at once and change image upon index selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
 <div v-for="i in 64" :key="i" class="pr-2 pb-2">       
 img
                v-if="selectedValues[i] && state.selected === true"
                :key="selectedValues[i]"
                class="cursor-pointer w-3.5 h-9"
                :src="img1"
                @click="multipleSelect(i)"
              />
              <img
                v-else
                class="cursor-pointer w-3.5 h-9"
                :src="img2"
                @click="multipleSelect(i)"
              />
</div>
    
    const state = reactive({
          selectedIndex: 0,
          selected: false,
        });
    
        let selected = ref();
        let selectedValues = [];
    
    
        function multipleSelect(index: number) {
          state.selectedIndex = index;
          state.selected = !state.selected;
          selected.value = index;
          for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            selectedValues.push({
              index: state.selected
            });
            console.log(index, selectedValues);
          }
        }
```

everything seems to be pushing to array properly in console but the images are not changing upon clicking
i had this working as selecting a single item only but i want to be able to select multiple at a time and add to the array and have it switch from img1 if they are selected img2 for group not selected

Answer (score 0):

`selectedValues` should be initialized as ref property in order to be reactive :

```
   let selectedValues = ref([]);

    function multipleSelect(index: number) {
      state.selectedIndex = index;
      state.selected = !state.selected;
      selected.value = index;
      for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        selectedValues.value.push({
                    // add .value 
          index: state.selected
        });
        console.log(index, selectedValues.value);
      }
    }
```

Comment: this is actually something i tried to do that i though would be right as well but i get this error when using ref([])

Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: Try out `let selectedValues = ref<Array<Record<string,boolean>>>([]);`

Comment: having    :key="selectedValues[i]" on the image elements returns an error 
 Type '{ [x: string]: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'string | number | undefined'.
  Type '{ [x: string]: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)         also this for some reason isnt selecting in the proper way its selecting what seems to be in length from the for loop not by index of whats being pushed to the selectedValues array